# Can't select the Subclass I want in Xcode, using cocos2d

Tags: xcode, file, cocos2d-iphone, subclass, subclassing

Im using cocos2d in Xcode and I am trying to select subclasses for my new file eg CCLayer or CCScene but only NSObject, UITableviewcell and UITableview are appearing in the drop down list, how do I assign the CC etc subclasses to the new file?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just ***type the class name*** in the text field. It seems Xcode list only the three basic and most customized classes *NSObject*, *UITableviewcell* and *UIView*.

If you can not type on it and you if are left only with those three options, simply select `NSObject` and in your `.h` file change `NSObject` to any class you want.

Comment: there is no field to type it into, just that drop down list thats whats confusing me

Comment: That is not a list box. That is a combo box. You can type in it.

Comment: trust me there is no way of typing. it is a dropdown with tick theres no way of entering my own subclass name.

Answer (score 0):

You can type the desired class name by hand into that drop down list. The mentioned drop down list only contains a few templates for most commonly subclassed classes. You can type in even class names you haven't created yes. It's just the string value for the template